# Does the singular series in the $k$-tuple conjecture always converge to an absolute constant?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory

The $k$-tuple conjecture can be found here https://mathworld.wolfram.com/k-TupleConjecture.html. Instead of using $C(m_1,\dots, m_k)$ as the constant in the conjecture, I prefer to use the singular series associated with $\textbf{m}=(m_1, \dots, m_k)$:
$$\mathfrak{S}(\textbf{m})=\prod_p \left(1-1/p\right)^{-k}\prod_p \left(1-\nu_p(\textbf{m})/p\right),
$$
where $\nu_p(\textbf{m})$ is the number of distinct residue class modulo $p$ for the elements of $\textbf{m}$ and $p$ denotes a prime, as usual. Since $\mathfrak{S}(\textbf{m})$ may not necessarily be the same for different $\textbf{m}$ with the same number of elements, i.e., $\mathfrak{S}((0,2,6))$ may not necessarily be the same as $\mathfrak{S}((0,4, 6))$, is $\mathfrak{S}(\textbf{m})$ always guaranteed to converge to an absolute constant for any admissible $\textbf{m}$? I know that this is the case, of course, for $\textbf{m}=(0,2)$, etc, but I am asking in the general sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't call it an *absolute* constant since it depends upon **m**. But yes, the singular series does converge for every admissible **m**, and thus equals a positive constant that depends upon **m**. (Indeed when **m** is not admissible, at least one of the quantities $\nu_p$(**m**) equals $0$, and so the singular series equals $0$ in this case, as it should.)

The convergence in the admissible case is not trivial but it's also standard for those in the know: the key fact is that the average value of $\nu_p$(**m**) as $p$ varies is equal to $k$ in the limit. This itself follows from the fact that an irreducible polynomial with integer coefficients has $1$ root per prime on average over primes, which is a consequence of the Prime Ideal Theorem.